# How does one graph higher exponents of $x$, $y$, and $z$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

For Beal's conjecture which is $A^x+B^y=C^z$ where $A$, $B$, and $C$ are positive integers and $x$, $y$, and $z$ are greater than $2$. I'm wondering how to even graph such an equation? WolframAlpha doesn't seem to do it and in my TI-84 Plus I get an error message.

I would appreciate only helpful voices.  Thanks.

Comment: There are 6 variable in the equation.  Are you trying for a 6-dimensional graph?  If you fix $A, B,$ and $C$ you still have a 3-D graph.  Wolfram could probably do it with an ImplicitPlot3D command (or whatever it is.)